# Why are there different patterns for escaping literal strings for use in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the reason for escaping more than you strictly need to when escaping literal strings for regex? Especially, why does google escape \x08?

[google closure library](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/string/string.js#L1134-L1143) version:

```
goog.string.regExpEscape = function(s) {
  return String(s).replace(/([-()\[\]{}+?*.$\^|,:#<!\\])/g, '\\$1').
      replace(/\x08/g, '\\x08');
};
```

vs the one in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters) for example

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

There has been some "what does it hurt?" "may as well" type of attitude at my work, but I am hesitant to use the google way since I don't understand it.

Comment: Did you try removing `.replace(/\x08/g, '\\x08')` in Closure? I believe it is redundant, and MDN version looks cleaner as it does not escape those characters that do not have to be escaped.

Comment: Is it not as simple as when two programmers write a program performing the same task, it's *rarely* gonna look exactly the same? It's a matter of preferences, skill etc. As for escaping unnecessary characters it could just be ignorance. Or laziness, not adapting the RE when copying from one flavor to another. (E.g. `/` has to be escaped in JS but not in python.)

Comment: reworded question to be more questiony.

Comment: The two functions differ mainly in the philosophies of the authors. The MDN function escapes only that which is known to need it. The author of the Closure function takes an approach that is more paranoid and superstitious, both in terms of what it escapes and how they implemented the escaping function itself. The Closure function's escaping of the characters `,` `:` `#` `<` `!` is definitely unnecessary, although harmless. Apparently the author of the Closure function didn't know about `$&` to insert the entire match in the replacement, so used a subgroup.

Comment: Doing `.replace(/\x08/g, '\\x08')` replaces literal backspace characters in the input string with an escaped form, but I can't see why you'd need to do that in a regex. A hypothesis: perhaps someone had a problem once upon a time with someone else using backspaces in a regex, and when displayed on a terminal during debugging the backspaces ate previous characters, which was confusing, so they escaped them, and that one-time kludge has stuck. It's almost definitely unnecessary.

Comment: There is one functional difference between the two, which relates to character classes. The MDN version doesn't escape `-`, so would allow `a-z` to match a range, rather than matching a literal `a`, `-`, and `z`. The difference probably doesn't matter in practice, as the main use of this function is for matching literal text, and it won't be used to embed user input in a character class. Outside a character class, the two escaping functions are identical. Overall I think the MDN function is more thoughtfully crafted.